# How to simply remove everything from a directory on Linux

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

How to simply remove everything from a current or specified directory on Linux?

Several approaches:

1. `rm -fr *`
   `rm -fr dirname/*`
   Does not work — it will leave hidden files — the one's that start with a dot, and files starting with a dash in current dir, and will not work with too many files
2. `rm -fr -- *`
   `rm -fr -- dirname/*`
   Does not work — it will leave hidden files and will not work with too many files
3. `rm -fr -- * .*`
   `rm -fr -- dirname/* dirname/.*`
   **Don't try this** — it will also remove a parent directory, because ".." also starts with a "."
4. `rm -fr * .??*`
   `rm -fr dirname/* dirname/.??*`
   Does not work — it will leave files like ".a", ".b" etc., and will not work with too many files
5. `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -fr`
   `find dirname -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -fr`
   As far as I know correct but not simple.
6. `find -delete`
   `find dirname -delete`
   AFAIK correct for current directory, but used with specified directory will delete that directory also.
7. `find -mindepth 1 -delete`
   `find dirname -mindeph 1 -delete`
   AFAIK correct, but is it the simplest way?

Comment: For number 3, it depends on the shell.  ZSH never expands . or .. on globs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rm -fr * .*`
Will work fine with at least GNU rm as it has special code to exclude "." and ".."

```
$ id
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir rmtest
$ cd rmtest
$ touch .test
$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4096 2009-08-19 15:37 .
drwxrwxrwt 7 root   root    4096 2009-08-19 15:37 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup    0 2009-08-19 15:37 .test
$ rm -rf .*
rm: cannot remove `.' or `..'
rm: cannot remove `.' or `..'
$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4096 2009-08-19 15:37 .
drwxrwxrwt 7 root   root    4096 2009-08-19 15:37 ..
$
```

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/remove.c#n440

FreeBSD rm man page says "It is an error to attempt to remove the files /, . or ..", so it probably works there too if you specify the force flag to ignore the error.

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rm&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.2-RELEASE&format=html

Comment: It will not work if there are too many files in this directory.

Answer (score 6):

To add to your list, lets say you want to delete everything in the directory foo and all sub directories (that is what your find command does).  I always found the simplest was:

```
#for dir foo with /home/kbrandt/foo
rm -rf /home/kbrandt/foo && mkdir /home/kbrandt/foo
```

If you don't want to delete the sub directories, modify your find command to include `-type f`

Comment: You'll then need to recreate ownership, permissions, labels (for selinux, acl etc.). Another process can have this directory opened. It just isn't simple.

Answer (score 4):

```
 rm -rf directory
```

It'll effectively nuke everything, including the directory itself.

Comment: yepp. so why not add "&& mkdir directory"?

Comment: There may be ACLs in effect that do not permit deletion of the directory. Also, you might have to preserve any ACL upon deletion and reapply it after creation.

Answer (score 1):

Why not a simple

```
ls -la <selected dir>| xargs rm -Rf
```

?

It will generate errors for "." & ".." but it will drop everything else.

Comment: Use ls -lA instead ...

Comment: It will not work, because "ls -lA" shows not only file names, but also permissions etc. "ls -A | xargs rm -Rf" will not work on files with spaces. Also often "ls" is an alias, which makes for example executables to display "*" after file name. This answer is so wrong.

Comment: Yep, ls is often an alias to a more complex command.
But I tried to give a simple answer with simple command.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that just worked for me:

```
zip -rm foo *
rm foo.zip
```

It may not be the most efficient method, but it worked.